# Plesk API - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, api, plesk, heredoc

I need to create a domain with the Plesk API. Everything works fine until I add the 'hosting' parameter.

**Without 'hosting':**

```
$request_create_domain = <<<EOF
<packet>
  <site>
   <add>
      <gen_setup>
        <name>example.com</name>
      </gen_setup>
    </add>
  </site>
</packet>
EOF;
```

**With hosting.** I get an internal server error. It still creates a domain but doesn't execute the full php script anymore.

```
$request_create_domain = <<<EOF
<packet>
  <site>
   <add>
      <gen_setup>
        <name>example.com</name>
      </gen_setup>
      <hosting>
        <vrt_hst>
              <property>
                <name>www_root</name>
                <value>/sample</value>
              </property>
        </vrt_hst>
      </hosting>
    </add>
  </site>
</packet>
EOF;
```

The website is running PHP7.1 as FastCGI application served by Apache. Executing the script via CLI gives me this error.

```
An incorrect PHP handler ID was specified. The following values are possible for php_handler_id: fastcgi, fpm, plesk-php71-fastcgi
```

The full script:

```
require 'class.plesk.php';


$plesk_client = new PleskApiClient('0.0.0.0');
$plesk_client->setCredentials('...', '...');


$request_create_domain = <<<EOF
<packet>
<site>
    <add>
      <gen_setup>
        <name>berryvandervelden.nl</name>
        <webspace-id>2</webspace-id>:
      </gen_setup>
      <hosting>
        <vrt_hst>
              <property>
                <name>www_root</name>
                <value>/berryvandervelden</value>
              </property>
        </vrt_hst>
      </hosting>
    </add>
  </site>
</packet>
EOF;


$response = $plesk_client->request($request_create_domain);
$answer_created_domain = simplexml_load_string($response);


if ($answer_created_domain->site->add->result->status == 'ok') {
    // Send mail.
}
```

Comment: @LucaJung Sorry, I forgot to add </vrt_hst>.

Comment: Check the error log to find the actual error message.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson 1. Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
2. End of script output before headers: plesk.create_domain.php    Apache error

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you get error 500 not from Plesk but from script. Please share full PHP script if you can.

And for API request you have forget about `<webspace-id>N</webspace-id>`:

```
<packet>
  <site>
   <add>
      <gen_setup>
        <name>example.com</name>
        <webspace-id>3</webspace-id>
      </gen_setup>
      <hosting>
        <vrt_hst>
              <property>
                <name>www_root</name>
                <value>/sample</value>
              </property>
        </vrt_hst>
      </hosting>
    </add>
  </site>
</packet>
```

Actually script is works for me:

```
<?php
require 'class.plesk.php';


$plesk_client = new PleskApiClient('127.0.0.1');
$plesk_client->setCredentials('admin', 'setup');


$request_create_domain = <<<EOF
<packet>
  <site>
   <add>
      <gen_setup>
        <name>example2.com</name>
        <webspace-id>3</webspace-id>
      </gen_setup>
      <hosting>
        <vrt_hst>
              <property>
                <name>www_root</name>
                <value>/sample</value>
              </property>
        </vrt_hst>
      </hosting>
    </add>
  </site>
</packet>
EOF;


$response = $plesk_client->request($request_create_domain);
var_dump($response);
$answer_created_domain = simplexml_load_string($response);


if ($answer_created_domain->site->add->result->status == 'ok') {
    // Send mail.
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. See my last edit, this is the full script. I only removed the plesk credentials for this post. class.plesk.php is from https://github.com/plesk/api-examples/blob/master/php/PleskApiClient.php

Comment: I've fixed request to `site` instead of `webspace`. And this script works fine for me, you may var_dump($response); to see actual response and execute it via CLI like: `php script.php`

Comment: I executed the script via CLI like you said and I'm getting this error: 'An incorrect PHP handler ID was specified. The following values are possible for php_handler_id: fastcgi, fpm, plesk-php71-fastcgi'.

Comment: Hm, it looks like some issues with PHP handler on parent subscription. You may try to create new subscription manually and try to create site with this request and new `webspace-id` again.